# connection time out in godaddy server

Tags: java, httpclient, vps, connection-timeout

if face problem just in Godaddy server when executing google API the request return connection time out,
only this request.
but on my other servers (digital ocean and local server), it runs and everything is well and same code and the same configuration

```
    String dataSTR = data.toString();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    StringEntity params = new StringEntity(dataSTR, "UTF-8");
    String key = "key=" + authKey;
    request.addHeader("Authorization", key);
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.addHeader("content-type", "charset=UTF-8");
    request.setEntity(params);
    System.out.println(request);
    System.out.println("______");
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        response = httpClient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(responseString);
        System.out.println(response);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Is `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` reachable from your godaddy server?

Comment: yes test it using curl

Comment: I contacted Godaddy support but no result